# Matlab ./ sign; basic matlab

Tags: matlab

I am a newbie to Matlab and am trying to figure out code. One thing that keeps returning and confusing me is the ./ sign. I tried googling and stackoverflowing it, but I can not find any documentation on it. Just googling ./ in combination with Matlab does not get me there.

To my understanding the code in the bottom does: Take the first record of the contry.farm.potatoes and divide this by all country.farm.tractors values summed. The result however is always a 0.x numbers. So from 0 to 1. Does that mean that the ./ sign makes sure it is a percentage?

```
country.farm.potatoes(1,:)./sum(country.farm.tractors,1)
```

Comment: It's in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/matlab-operators-and-special-characters.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**General explanation**

the following code does the following:

(1) takes the first row of country.farm.potatoes

(2) generate a vector such that the i'th coordinate is the sum of the i'th column of country.farm.tractors

(3) divides each coordinate of (1) by the corresponding coordinate in (2).

**(:,1) syntax**

Given a matrix M of size m,n, the syntax '(:,1)' extracts the first row of the matrix.
It generates a row vector of size 1xn.

```
M(1,:)
```

**sum(M,1) syntax**

Given a matrix M of size m,n, the syntax sum(M,1) generates a row vecotr of size 1xn,
s.t each coordinate j is the sum of the j'th column of the matrix.

```
sum(M,1)
```

**A ./ B syntax**

Given two matrices or vectors A,B (of same size),  the syntax 'C=A./B' yields a per coordinate division result.
This means that C(i,j)=A(i,j)/B(i,j)

```
C = A./B
```

for example:

```
[9,6,2] ./ [3,3,2]

ans =     3     2     1
```